# Shopify: create a smart collection for products that do NOT have a specific tag

Tags: shopify

In Shopify I have a smart collection for all the product that have the "wholesale" tag.

I'd like to create also another smart collection for all the remaining products that do NOT have the "wholesale" tag.
Is this possible?  Is there a workaround?

Maybe creating a smart collection is not the best possible option.  What I really need to do is just list 6 products that do NOT have the "wholesale" tag.  Is there an easy way to do this?

Thanks in advance,
Augusto

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a custom collection and add the individual products to it. At this time you cannot create a smart collection based on not having a tag. If you wanted to automate this you could have a web hook listen to product create/update and adjust the collection when the tags are changed.

Comment: Hi there,
Is is still impossible to create a smart collection based on "tag is not equal to"? Just wondering why this has been the case. It seems pretty straightforward

Answer (score 1):

There is this "Power Tools - Bulk Edit Tags" app: http://apps.shopify.com/power-tools-bulk-edit-tags